# Ads not showing up in AdView

Tags: android, admob

I am new to integrate AdMob with android. I got a issue that Ads not showing up in AdView. I already linked firebase to my AdMob account. Upto my findings this should display ads. But I don't know Why this occurs

My Activity,

```
MobileAds.initialize(MainActivity.this, "my-id");

AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorGrey"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My log,

```
04-16 19:38:26.146 10178-10268/com.example.my.app W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
04-16 19:38:26.150 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
04-16 19:38:26.150 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
04-16 19:38:26.151 10178-10178/com.example.my.app I/Ads: Starting ad request.
04-16 19:38:26.154 10178-10178/com.example.my.app I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("FFD5F3261542E02E3D30EE7D21F08733") to get test ads on this device.
04-16 19:38:26.157 10178-10178/com.example.my.app W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
04-16 19:38:26.177 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
04-16 19:38:26.177 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
04-16 19:38:26.183 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
04-16 19:38:26.183 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
04-16 19:38:26.196 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
04-16 19:38:26.201 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
04-16 19:38:26.211 10178-10279/com.example.my.app W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
04-16 19:38:26.211 10178-10279/com.example.my.app W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
04-16 19:38:26.213 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
04-16 19:38:26.216 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
04-16 19:38:26.218 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
04-16 19:38:26.221 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
04-16 19:38:26.226 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
04-16 19:38:26.227 10178-10178/com.example.my.app D/AppTracker: App Event: start
04-16 19:38:26.236 10178-10183/com.example.my.app I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=43KB
04-16 19:38:26.247 10178-10183/com.example.my.app I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=43KB
04-16 19:38:26.247 10178-10183/com.example.my.app I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
04-16 19:38:26.270 10178-10264/com.example.my.app W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
04-16 19:38:26.324 10178-10264/com.example.my.app I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
04-16 19:38:26.578 10178-10315/com.example.my.app W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/com.example.my.app/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
04-16 19:38:26.579 10178-10178/com.example.my.app I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.appcache", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
04-16 19:38:26.580 10178-10178/com.example.my.app I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
04-16 19:38:26.746 10178-10288/com.example.my.app W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
04-16 19:38:26.750 10178-10178/com.example.my.app W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
04-16 19:38:26.953 10178-10178/com.example.my.app I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40-loader.html (0)
04-16 19:38:48.880 10178-10178/com.example.my.app D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
04-16 19:41:11.526 10178-10178/com.example.my.app D/AppTracker: App Event: start
04-16 19:41:41.449 10178-10178/com.example.my.app D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: change the width to wrap_content like this one   android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: Have you added INTERNET permission?

Comment: @NhaT.Tran yes added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes ads are not matched, and it's not displayed. you should add listener to AdView and check out the error code.

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
         System.out.println("onAdLoaded() CALLBACK");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
         System.out.println("onAdFailedToLoad() CALLBACK code: " + errorCode);
    }
});
```

Comment: As i said, sometimes you don't get any ad, it's good to use mediation. I can't remember what was the code for. Search SO for onAdFailedToLoad() CALLBACK code: 0 and you will find the answer. I sometimes get 2 or 3.

Comment: I also do that you say. and onAdLoaded() is called but ads do not show.